# To Pull the outer HTML content and create the XHTML using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to create the html using xslt transform by fetching the information from outer html file:

My Input XML file:

```
<topic xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" xmlns:r="http://www.Corecms.com/Core/ns/metadata" class="- topic/topic " ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.2" domains="(topic hi-d) (topic indexing-d) (topic d4p_formatting-d) a(props d4p_renditionTarget) (topic d4p_math-d) (topic d4p_variables-d) (topic d4p_verse-d) (topic learningInteractionBase2-d learning2-d+learning-d) (topic learningBase+learningInteractionBase-d) (topic learningInteractionBase-d) (topic learningInteractionBase2-d) (topic xml-d) a(base CoreIdAtt) (topic sdClassification-d) a(base contentstore) " id="T1" outputclass="interactive" r:CoreId="4567">
       <title class="- topic/title "/>
       <body class="- topic/body ">
              <bodydiv class="- topic/bodydiv ">
                     <xref class="- topic/xref " format="html" href="1234.html" scope="external"/>
              </bodydiv>
       </body>
</topic>
```

I have called html file using  element. The corresponding **1234.html** file code is:

```
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <h1>New HTML test with XSL transformation</h1>
        <p>this is a new test about rsuite-edit opening HTML files</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

XSL I have tried as like below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
        xmlns:r="http://www.Corecms.com/Core/ns/metadata" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
        xmlns:df="http://dita2indesign.org/dita/functions"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd r exsl xhtml ditaarch df" version="2.0">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:function name="df:class" as="xs:boolean">
            <xsl:param name="elem" as="element()"/>
            <xsl:param name="classSpec" as="xs:string"/>

            <xsl:variable name="normalizedClassSpec" as="xs:string" select="normalize-space($classSpec)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="result"
                select="matches($elem/@class, concat(' ', $normalizedClassSpec, ' | ', $normalizedClassSpec, '$'))"
                as="xs:boolean"/>

            <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
        </xsl:function>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="html">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$html"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')]">
            <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="contenteditable">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(ancestor::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')])">

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="generate-comments"/>

                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/title')][parent::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')]]">
            <xsl:variable name="headingLevel" select="count(ancestor::*[df:class(., 'topic/topic')])"
                as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:element name="h{$headingLevel}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/body')]">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/bodydiv')]">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/p')]">
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". != ''">
                    <a>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                        NO URL PROVIDED
                    </a>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting output as like:

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-coreid="4567" html-coreid="1234"> <!-- Where 1234 is the core ID of the HTML file and 4567 is the DITA topic core ID.  -->
      <article>
           <h1>New</h1>
           <p>this is a new test</p>
      </article>
</div>
```

I need to fetch the external html content (1234.html) and create the new xhtml file using the XSLT. I'm new to the XSL. Your Help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that **1234.html** is parseable as mentioned in the answer by Ferestes like

```
<article>
   <h1>New</h1>
   <p>this is a new test</p>
</article>
```

you can use the line

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)"/>
```

in your `*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]` template to copy the *well-formed* content of your **1234.html** (the name in the `href` attribute) file.

---

EDIT (relating to edited question):

The whole template could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[df:class(., 'topic/xref')]">
  <div contenteditable="true" data-coreid="{ancestor::topic/@r:CoreId}" html-coreid="{substring-before(@href,'.')}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" contenteditable="true" data-coreid="4567" html-coreid="1234">
    <html xmlns="">
        <head/>
        <body>
            <h1>New HTML test with XSL transformation</h1>
            <p>this is a new test about rsuite-edit opening HTML files</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @zx485. I have edited my html as parseable. But <xsl:copy-of> is not working on that template. Please provide me some other suggestion.

Comment: With your edit you changed the content of 1234.html, but that doesn't matter, it still works the same. But now it is out-of-sync with your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @zx485. Its working fine. But how to get  html-coreid="1234" in the attribute for div

Answer (score 2):

Usually `document()` is used to retrieve external nodes. The external document must be parseable. There are a lot of parts in your stylesheet, which make not so much sense in my opinion, eg. you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` to process attributes, but since you have no template for attributes, only their text-nodes will be extraced.

Comment: Thanks @ferestes. I have tried document() is not working. Or otherwise change the external html as valid one and try on this issue. Please provide me some suggestion on this